# Bash Function Grep Mod

Tags: bash, grep, function

> TL:DR How do I add a grep to a bash function while allowing a variable number of optional inputs?

I find that in repeated grepping of large outputs, I end up clogging the terminal with data.  Sometimes, I want to do a grep, and quickly go to the top of it while capturing all the data.  To this end, I have become accustomed with using "clear;clear; grep [options] [string] [file] ; top".  Being lazy, I want to turn this into a function called "cgrep", which performs the two clears and the grep.  What I have tried is:

```
cgrep () {
   clear
   clear
   grep "$1" "$2" "$3"
}
```

This works, providing that I always use exactly one optional argument.  While that isn't a problem most of the time, I became curious about how to feed it 0-N optional arguments without causing issues (such as reading the [string] as [file]).

I've read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274175/optional-parameters-in-bash-function), and tried a similar implementation.  However, this didn't quite suit my needs, and it would be better if I could have the optional parameters between cgrep and [string] to make it look more like a traditional grep.

Comment: Are you asking how the function can test for no arguments and exit with a message rather than invoke the clear and grep commands?

Comment: @SottoVoce I'm hoping to learn how to invoke the grep command correctly with 0-N optional parameters.  Currently, 0 parameters will try to use [string] as an optional parameter, and 2 parameters will try to use [string] as [file].  Is there a way for the function to understand what is or isn't an optional parameter, just like running grep by itself through the terminal would?

Comment: Why would you call `clear` twice in a row?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas One clear will get rid of most of the buffer, but it leave the previous called output of top at the top of the window.  Using clear twice will truly remove all entries from the buffer, so I know that if I scroll all the way up, I will be at the top of what I just queried.  This just makes checking things a little bit faster, and it looks nicer.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your `clear` or terminal emulator. What terminal emulator are you using? What's the output of `echo "$TERM"; clear | LC_ALL=C sed -n l`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm using xterm.  Output is:
_xterm
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: missing command_

Comment: That's a lower case `L` (`l`), not `1` digit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas _xterm
\033[3;J\033[H\033[2J$_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash and sh `"$@"` will expand all positional parameters so:

```
cgrep () {
   clear
   clear
   grep "$@"
}
```

Note that `$@` has to be double quoted to prevent word splitting, globbing, empty removal, etc from being performed on each parameter.

[3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters)

Comment: Tried it and it worked perfectly!  Will set it as the accepted answer asap!  Thanks!

Comment: It's not only word-splitting that quoting `$@` prevents, it's also globbing (split+glob), and empty removal.